# Comparing two columns in excel, returning data into another cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need help creating a formula in Excel 2010.

I have two worksheets - one that is a detail tab that is populated quarterly (Worksheet1), and the other one is a summary tab (Worksheet2).

In Column A of both worksheets I have a list of names.  The formula needs to compare the names and if there is a match, Column E of Worksheet 2 needs to be populated with the data in Column C of Worksheet 1.

Please help - I have been banging my head on my desk all morning trying to figure this out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In column E of sheet 2, use a conditional expression.  For example, for row 1:

```
=IF(A1 = Sheet1!A1, Sheet1!C1, "" )
```

Copy this formula to every row of column E.